# access private static function from closure called in global function php 5.3.5

Tags: php, closures, static-methods, php-5.3, private-members

I have encountered a strange problem. I am working on a program which should work on PHP5.3 . Today, a server with PHP5.3.5 installed gave me the following error when running my program:
`Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active on line 19`

I do not have this problem on any other server with later PHP versions. But I have to find a solution nevertheless.
To make the problem easy to understand, I made the following little script. Basically I call a global function with a closure as parameter which calls a private static function.
I researched this problem and it seems `Closure::bind` would be the solution, but is only available for PHP5.4+. I need a solution for PHP5.3 and I am at a dead end.

```
<?php

function doSth($c)
{
    $c();
}

class foo
{
    private static function bar()
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }

    public static function go()
    {
        doSth(function()
        {
            self::bar();
        });
    }
}

foo::go();
```

Comment: Try: `doSth(function() using (self) { self::bar(); });`

Comment: @Sammitch: do you mean `use`? Unfortunately it seems that this is not allowed. (`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE`)

Answer (score -1):

No need to declare self... you need to call the function this way:

$this->bar() not self::bar();

Comment: Since this function is static, $this will not even be initialized.

Comment: ah.... you would do foo::bar(). Also are you sure you want the function to be private and not protected? Another option would be adding in an init function that returns self.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I want it to be private. That's how my class works. Hmm. I doubt the getInstance() function will work since PHP thinks it is outside the class. But I will give it a try - you never know.

Comment: Well. Just as I thought. It won't work that way :/  In the past few days I have begun to suspect that this is a bug in PHP 5.3.5 since it works in later versions.